# Solaris 11: Node.JS: Could not autodetect OpenSSL support

Tags: node.js, build, openssl, solaris

How do I resolved this error on Solaris 11?

`"Could not autodetect OpenSSL support. Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. Use configure --without-ssl to disable this message."`

It is odd because I know that I have `openssl` `1.0.0e`.

Also I know that Node is looking in `/usr/include` and that the files `/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h` and `/usr/include/openssl/crypto.h` exist.

[Ubuntu Equivalent](http://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs-error-could-not-autodetect-openssl-support.html)

Answer (score 3):

The "OpenSSL development packages" are actually not the "openssl" package.

You need to apt-get *(or similar for Solaris)* install the package called "libssl-dev".
For me, this solved the problem while trying to configure the source for node.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you have openssl already installed in `/usr/local/ssl`, use those configure options:

```
--openssl-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include --openssl-libpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

Comment: Source? Where did you find this?